# Skip Windows Authentication with Selenium / Jenkins

Tags: firefox, authentication, testing, automated-tests, windows-authentication

I use Selenium IDE to create my tests
I integrate these tests with selenium modules in Jenkins and all is OK.

My problem is that on my test site there is an authentication "windows" impossible to manage directly with selenium commands.

I try to change my base URL http://username:password@site.com/
But it does not work (I use Firefox)

What would be the solutions to this problem?
A JS solution perhaps? In my user-extensions.js ?

**Thank you for help !**

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting some kind of popup asking to enter user name and password, then Robot() class is handy to help you. Robot class is used to type characters using keyboard. Just use `package java.awt.*;`

How: First set a clipboard of user name and type it in dialog and then do the same for password.

Sample Code:

```
        stringSelection = new StringSelection(clipBoardForWindows);
                            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);

                            Thread.sleep(250);

                            //Paste the file path by typing key
                            rt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                            rt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

                            Thread.sleep(250);    

    // Release key
                            rt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                            rt.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);

//Press and release enter key
                                Thread.sleep(250);    
    rt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                        rt.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope this helps, you can type any key just by changing code `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER`.